# Django Model __str__ called several times

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have created a Django Model as follow :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='people', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_holding = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_write_permission = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(to=Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have define `__str__` like this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

I have include a print before my return and I have observed that when saving an object, `__str__` was called several times (4 times to be exact). I am wondering why is that the case ? Is it normal ?

I have explored the source code of save [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py), line 658, but cannot find the answer.

This is not a question related to queries to database.

Comment: Can you show the script that performs the save operation?

Comment: Are you sure it's four times on the same instance, rather than four separate instances?

Comment: Hello @Sanip, I don't use a script. I do it manually going on Django Admin interface clicking save.

Comment: @DanielRoseman not sure to understand. It prints 4 times inside the `__str__` although I clicked only once on save in interface. Thanks for your help